# Handlebars Helpers in {{each}} block

Tags: javascript, marionette, handlebars.js

I'm using Marionette and Handlebars, and so far I've been able to use the following template helper just fine:

```
templateHelpers: function(){
    return {
        formatDate: function(dateString) {
            var dateWithOffset = new Date(dateString);
            var dateWithoutOffset = new Date(dateWithOffset.getTime() + dateWithOffset.getTimezoneOffset() * 1000 * 60);
            return dateWithoutOffset.toLocaleDateString();
            }
}
```

However, when I try to use it in my .hbs inside an {{each}} block I get an error.

```
{{#each mi.Comments}}
    {{formatDate date}}</br>
{{/each}}
```

mi.Comments does indeed have a date attribute and if I remove the formatDate, it displays the unformatted date properly for each comment.

Here is the error I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Missing helper: "formatDate"
```

Any guidance is appreciated. This is part of a larger project with multiple other developers and I'm hoping to not use the HandleBars.registerHelper method, so I don't need to modify my base widget file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, when the {{#each}} block changes the context, it also changes the context for helper functions. This code in the .hbs works:

```
{{#each mi.Comments}}
   {{../formatDate date}}</br>
{{/each}}
```

The '../' tells Handlebars to look at the parent of the current context, which is where the helper function resides.

Comment: Hmmmm, that's interesting! Well, I could have told you about the "path" syntax, but I had no idea that you could define View-specific Handlebars helpers that way, but it looks like that's exactly what you've done. Awesome.